# Spring KafkaStreams not receiving messages only in tests

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have problem with Spring and KafkaStreams but only in tests.
Test looks like below

```
@Autowired
private StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;

@Test
@DirtiesContext
void shouldHandleUserCreatedEvent() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        streamsBuilder.stream("TESTTOPIC").peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("received_from_test"));
    }).start();

    var event = UserCreatedEvent.builder()
            .userId("userid")
            .login("mockedLogin")
            .build();
    reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send("TESTTOPIC", event.getUserId(), event).block();

    StepVerifier.create(Flux.interval(Duration.of(30, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)))
            .expectError().verify();
}
```

and after this test message "received_from_test" is not printed.

But when I create similar stream in my app for example like below:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    streamsBuilder.stream("TESTTOPIC").peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("received_from_app"));
}
```

message "received_from_app" is printed.
Maybe somebody could help me and tell whats wrong with above test?

PS.
new Thread() is only to exclude problem with Threads (blocking or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

I have suspicion that StreamsBuilder.build() method is called after app starts and this topology is used. After app starts any other method call on builder have no impact on stream processing.
If I want to use this topology in tests I need to create new KafkaStreams and pass modified topology to it